# facebook graph api for public information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able access the wall (public) contents of an unknown person through graph API, but not his info.

```
graph.facebook.com/xyz.abc/feed&access_token=yadayadayada
```

Why do I need the user's permission (oauth) to get his info through graph when it is available on facebook.com/xyz.abc/?sk=info

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it wrong, that is just the Facebook API's policy and how it has always worked.  To get user info from the API, a user has to approve it or one of their friends has to approve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. is there any other way/script to get the info directly from facebook.com/username?

Comment: The same way you would scrape any other web page.  But you risk getting sued by Facebook.

Comment: Screen scraping?  But I think Facebook would frown upon this method.

Comment: LOL, two of the same responses at once  :)